# No more space for Pokemon

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I want the egg from the day care pokemon please but I already have no space left for the day care
and me can anyone help?

Comment: While we can guess what you're trying, the question really doesn't help at all. You might want to rewrite it in a way so we can understand it.

Answer (score 5):

**To pick up an egg, you have to deposit your Pokémon so that you have 5 or less Pokémon with you.**

There are three options to deposit a massive amount of Pokémons:

1. **Your Pokémon PC.** You can use, for example, the PC to the right of a nurse in a Pokémon Center. In the first selection you can use 31 Boxes plus the Battle Box to deposit your Pokémon there. If you catch a wild Pokémon while already having six in your team, they also end up there.
2. **Another game module.** If you're lucky and have a sibling who also owns X or Y, you can trade with him/her so that he can use his own boxes as described in (1).
3. **Use the [Pokémon Bank](http://www.pokemonbank.com/en-us/), Luke!** It's like your box system described in (1) with the difference that it can store up to 3.000 Pokémons. Info how to download this extra software in [the link](http://www.pokemonbank.com/en-us/).

If all of these are bursting at the seams, you have to set your Pokémon free. Sometimes you just have to let them [ramble on](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uKVp-atyiVA).

Answer (score 2):

If you deposit one of your Pokemon in the PC, you can come back to the Daycare Man and pick up the Egg.